# The primitive type of R does not have a field drawable

Tags: android, eclipse, r.java-file

I get the error-message:

```
The primitive type of R does not have a field drawable
```

For the code:

```
mark = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
.position(new LatLng(latO, lonO))
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker)));
```

I've tried:

1. Add import `com.example.testmap.R`;
2. Clean project, build project
3. Clean project, leave eclipse, start eclipse, build project

Everytime I get a `R.java` file which contains drawable and the marker as well. 
Any suggestions what else one can try?

*note: never imported com.android.R

Answer (score 0):

"Fixed it" by doing:

```
mark = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
.position(new LatLng(latO, lonO))
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(com.example.testmap.R.drawable.marker)));
```

Still dont know why I can't just use R.drawable.marker directly. :S

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while, but I just ended up here from a Google search on this same issue. For me, I had created a variable named R inside the class, which overrode the class reference to R. Renaming the variable and/or referencing the R class using its absolute name fixed the issue.